# How to print object value in Angular Template

Tags: angular

I am trying to print object value by {{object-name}} but I am getting no response as its not printing, not sure what i am missing;

### Class

```
export class RadioButtonQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
controlType = 'radio';
     options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];  // I need to print this object for radio

constructor(options: {} = {}) {
  super(options);
  this.options = options['options'] || [];
}
```

### MetaData

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new RadioButtonQuestion ({
    key: 'eating-ice-cream',
    label: 'What ice-crea you like to eat?',
    order: 6,
    options: [
      {name:'ice-cream', key: 'Vanilla',  value: 'Vanilla'},
      {name:'ice-cream', key: 'banana',  value: 'banana'},
      {name:'ice-cream', key: 'apple',   value: 'apple'},
    ],
  })
 ];
```

In following code, {{opt.value}} doesn't print any value, ???

### Template

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">radio
   <small>radio</small> 
      <input *ngFor="let opt of question.options" type="radio" [name]="opt.name" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: can you try {{obj | json }} instead {{obj.value}} and check if `value` is available

Comment: `let opt of question.options`. But your variable is called `questions`. Do you have a loop over your template  ?

Comment: first of all, use ng-for on ng-container instead of the input tag, also provide id, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: no when I use |, it throw error  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'value' could not be found ("     <input *ngFor="let opt of question.options" type="radio" [name]="opt.name" [value]="opt.key">{{[ERROR ->]opt|value}}
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. You currently have `let opt of question.options` and it should be `let opt of questions.options`

Your code should be:

```
<input *ngFor="let opt of questions.options" type="radio" [name]="opt.name" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}
```

Also I don't believe you want to use the *ngFor on your actual `input`

Try wrapping your inputs in a div and use the *ngFor there:

```
<div *ngFor="let opt of options.questions" >
  <input type="radio" [value]="opt.key"/> {{opt.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got working; also add checkbox

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">radio
  <small>radio</small> 
    <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options" >
        <input type="radio" [name]="opt.name" [value]="opt.key"/> {{opt.value}}
    </div> 
</div>

 <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
  <small>checkbox</small>
  <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options" >
        <input type="checkbox" [name]="opt.name" [value]="opt.key"/> {{opt.value}}
    </div>      
</div>
```